# NSNotification sent once, but is received multiple times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I am communicating between two classes with NSNotificationCenter. My problem is that although I tap a button once (and that button only fires off once) I am unintentionally producing increasing numbers of notifications from only one call to the NSNotificationCenter.

Here is a better explanation of the problem, with code:

---

My two classes are the **mainView** class and the **Menu** class.

When a view in the **mainView** class is tapped, it launches a view created and governed by the **Menu** class. This code is called when the **mainView** is initialized:

```
menu=[[MyMenu alloc] init];
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTapped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[container addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onChangeItem:) name:@"ItemChange" object:nil];
```

This Gesture Recognizer fires off this method, also in the **mainView** class:

```
- (void) onTapped: (UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
    NSLog(@"tap");
    [menu displayMenu];
}
```

This is how the **Menu** class initializes:

```
- (MyMenu*) init {
    self=[super init];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout * layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    menuView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [menuView setDataSource:self];
    [menuView setDelegate:self];
    [menuView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [menuView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [menuView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [menuView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [menuView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite];
    return self;
}
```

And this is the `displayMenu` method inside the **Menu** class:

```
- (void) displayMenu {
    [viewForMenu addSubview:menuView];
}
```

The **Menu** class also has a `clearMenu` method:

```
- (void) clearMenu {
    [menuView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This is the code for each cell in the UICollectionView, contained within my **Menu** class:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell * cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    NSLog(@"button tapped : %d",indexPath.row);
    return cell;
}
```

This calls the `onButtonTapped:` method, also within my **Menu** class:

```
- (void) onButtonTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
    NSInteger buttonTapped=[[recognizer view] tag];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ItemChange" object:nil userInfo:@{@"selected":@(buttonTapped)}];
[self clearMenu];
}
```

This notification is picked up by my **mainView** class with this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onChangeItem:) name:@"ItemChange" object:nil];
```

This calls the `onChangeItem:` method, inside my **mainView** class:

```
- (void) onChangeItem: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"change item to %d",[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"clock"] intValue]);
}
```

So that's the code.

---

OK, here's the problem: the first time the menu displays I get this in my log:

```
...[43023:11f03] tap
...[43023:11f03] button tapped : 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
```

And this is fine, this is what I expect. However second time around I get this:

```
...[43023:11f03] tap
...[43023:11f03] button tapped : 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
```

Third time around I get this:

```
...[43023:11f03] tap
...[43023:11f03] button tapped : 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
...[43023:11f03] change item to 1
```

And so on. Each successive tap on a menu item doubles the amount of notification calls.

---

To begin with I thought I was adding multiple views, and thus resulting in multiple button taps, and therefore multiple notifications calls.

However as you can see from my logs, this is not the case. **The buttons are only receiving 1 tap event - this is firing off only 1 notification - but receiving class gets sent multiple notifications.**

Can anyone explain this to me?

Sorry for the lengthy post!

Comment: Where in the code you are calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onChangeItem:) name:@"ItemChange" object:nil];` and removing it ? In your `onChangeItem:` method print memory address of `self` which is observing the notification `NSLog(@"%p",self);` and show us what you see in console.

Comment: This is called when the **mainView** is initialized. So it is called only once.

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"%p",self);` in your `onChangeItem:` method and show us what you see in console

Comment: You're adding a new tap gesture recognizer to the cell every time a cell is reused. You should check if one exists on the cell first before adding one.

Comment: @rdelmar How would I check if one exists?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, I am assuming that `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onChangeItem:) name:@"ItemChange" object:nil];` are being added more than once.

I like to remove any potential observer before adding an observer, like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ItemChange" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onChangeItem:) name:@"ItemChange" object:nil];
```

That way there will ever only be one observer callback.

Comment: @Jimmery If you do a global search for "addObserver:" is there a "removeObserver:" above each one?

Comment: Oh. Ok. I am an idiot, I put your code in the wrong place. Now that it is in the right place it fixes my bug! Thank you so much :) I wish I could offer you more than just fake internet points!

Comment: i have the same problem, but iam sure that i have exactly called addObserver just once, but iam getting the callback twice, with exectly the same notification object (notifications have the same memory adress and content)

Comment: 4 years later and you get more fake internet points! This helped me out of a jam!

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:** I faced same problem, observer was calling twice, sometimes thrice.

> **Scenario**
>
> 1. A user taps logout button
> 2. `HomeViewController` was dismissed and `LoginViewController` screen was presented
> 3. When user signed in again for second time
> 4. Observer was called twice (sometimes thrice)

The issue was `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in `dealloc` method of my `HomeViewController` was not called at all, which actually removes an object from the notification center all together.

> ℹ️ `dealloc` is an Objective-C selector that is sent by the
>   Objective-C runtime to an object when the object is no longer owned by
>   any part of the application.

**Solution:**  Made your own method `dispose` and call it when user tap `logout`.

```
- (void)dealloc { 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    // ....
}

- (void)dispose { 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)logoutTapped { 
    [self dispose];
    // ....
}
```